# Is there a way I can use a different extension than .txt such as .log or .csv when using ApprovalTests?

Tags: approval-tests

I want the content to remain a text file, so code such as:

```
Approvals.Verify("some actual result as text");
```

Should continue to work.   But I would like the approval tests to write to a ..approval.csv file or a ..approval.log file instead of ..approval.txt file.

I looked through the code and I think I may need to create a custom IApprovalWriter, but I also notice that the ExtensionWithDot property is read/write, so I'm wondering how this can be set.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
ApprovalTests.Approvals.Verify(WriterFactory.CreateTextWriter(text, fileExtensionWithoutDot));
```

or for your example:

```
Approvals.Verify(WriterFactory.CreateTextWriter("some actual result as text", "log"));
```

Happy Testing!